# How should I specify signing key for app?

Tags: android, android-build

In my Android ROM I've generated my own signing keys and also added an additional key (defined in system/external/sepolicy/keys.conf) that I would like to sign certain applications with. However, I don't know how to do just that? Everything seems to get signed with the Platform key by default, so not sure how to specify the key. Is this something I need to do in the makefile or post ROM build?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution turned out to be very simple. Simply specify the signing key in the Android.mk for the application by using the LOCAL_CERTIFICATE tag.

```
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := my_key
```

Comment: And be careful of `LOCAL_CERTIFICATE` , delete the prefix/suffix **space** of the value.